# How can i pick a number from an array in C?

Tags: c

Basically i made an array with number 1,2,3.

```
int array[3] = {1,2,3};
```

How can I select a random number from this list and assign it to a different variable?

Comment: That would be `array[x] = number`, `x` is a number ranging from 0-2.

Comment: @alex01011 You mean `number = array[x]`?

Comment: Someone's already given you an answer, but: If you'd like to be able to solve problems like these for yourself, the way to do it is like any other: break it down into smaller parts.  You need to (a) pick a random number from 0..2, (b) fetch that element from your array, and (c) assign the fetched value to a new variable.  Which of these things do you know how to do already?  Which do you need to do more research, or ask questions about, before you can proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`rand()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rand.3.html) function and mod the result down to 3 values 0, 1, or 2 using mod. Then access the corresponding value in your array:

```
    srand(time(NULL));//  without this rand() function might continuously give the same value
    int index = rand() % 3;
    printf("random: %d\n", array[index]);
```

Considering that the array contains hardcoded values, you could simply:

```
int i = (rand() % 3) + 1;
printf("random: %d\m", i);
```

Include the header file `<stdio.h>`, `<time.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`